# Webscraping Getting json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Invalid control

Tags: python, json, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, multiprocessing

I am getting prices from a website and I have developed the following script. However, when adding more urls I get the error you can see down. There are over 100 urls in the urls list.

```
import json
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
from multiprocessing import Pool
import pandas as pd

data = {'url':[],'offers_price':[]}

def get_price(url):
    soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url, headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'}).content, "html.parser")
    data = json.loads(soup.find_all('script', {'type': 'application/ld+json'})[-1].get_text())
    return url, int(data['offers']['price'])

if __name__ == '__main__':

    urls = [
        'https://www.tiffany.co.uk/jewelry/necklaces-pendants/tiffany-infinity-pendant-37725951/',
        'https://www.tiffany.co.uk/jewelry/necklaces-pendants/return-to-tiffany-tiffany-blue-heart-tag-charm-GRP09431/',
        'https://www.tiffany.co.uk/jewelry/necklaces-pendants/mum-medium-heart-tag-pendant-72155610/',
        'https://www.tiffany.co.uk/jewelry/necklaces-pendants/mum-medium-heart-tag-pendant-72155637/',
        'https://www.tiffany.co.uk/jewelry/necklaces-pendants/return-to-tiffany-heart-tag-charm-GRP03712/',
        'https://www.tiffany.co.uk/jewelry/necklaces-pendants/paloma-picasso-olive-leaf-heart-pendant-30143159/',
        'https://www.tiffany.co.uk/jewelry/necklaces-pendants/return-to-tiffany-heart-tag-pendant-30971655/',
        'https://www.tiffany.co.uk/jewelry/necklaces-pendants/return-to-tiffany-mini-double-heart-tag-pendant-GRP06366/',
        'https://www.tiffany.co.uk/jewelry/necklaces-pendants/return-to-tiffany-mini-double-heart-tag-pendant-63520594/',
        'https://www.tiffany.co.uk/jewelry/necklaces-pendants/paloma-picasso-olive-leaf-pendant-33419724/',
        'https://www.tiffany.co.uk/jewelry/necklaces-pendants/tiffany-twist-knot-pendant-29849498/',
        'https://www.tiffany.co.uk/jewelry/necklaces-pendants/return-to-tiffany-lovestruck-heart-tag-pendant-online-exclusive-70878216/',
        'https://www.tiffany.co.uk/jewelry/necklaces-pendants/tiffany-infinity-pendant-GRP06365/',
        'https://www.tiffany.co.uk/jewelry/necklaces-pendants/return-to-tiffany-mini-double-heart-tag-pendant-28751249/',
        'https://www.tiffany.co.uk/jewelry/necklaces-pendants/return-to-tiffany-heart-tag-charm-GRP05849/',
        .
        .
        .
        'https://www.tiffany.co.uk/jewelry/necklaces-pendants/elsa-peretti-diamonds-by-the-yard-sprinkle-necklace-62356812/'
    ]

    with Pool(processes=4) as pool:
            for url, price in pool.imap_unordered(get_price, urls):
                    data['offers_price'].append(price)
                    data['url'].append(url)
    tiffany_necklace = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

The error I get refers to some Invalid control character as below:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 125, in worker
    result = (True, func(*args, **kwds))
  File "/Users/marco/PycharmProjects/hardluxuryprices/tiffany.py", line 11, in get_price
    data = json.loads(soup.find_all('script', {'type': 'application/ld+json'})[-1].get_text())
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/json/__init__.py", line 346, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/json/decoder.py", line 337, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/json/decoder.py", line 353, in raw_decode
    obj, end = self.scan_once(s, idx)
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Invalid control character at: line 5 column 193 (char 292)
"""

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/marco/PycharmProjects/hardluxuryprices/tiffany.py", line 301, in <module>
    for url, price in pool.imap_unordered(get_price, urls):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 870, in next
    raise value
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Invalid control character at: line 5 column 193 (char 292)

Process finished with exit code 1
```

I was thinking that maybe some links were not working, or have been disrupted, but I haven't checked. How could I overcome this to happen? I am not super familiar with multiprocessing. Thanks!

Comment: I realised that some urls create this problem, although the JSON/HTML structure seems correct. Is there anyway I can skip the URL that create this problem while looping, maybe an if statement?

Comment: Also for some working urls when the list is too long, I get Index out of range error. I overcame this by creating small subset, but still don't get my head around it.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way of getting that information:

```
import requests
import pandas as pd
from tqdm.notebook import tqdm

pd.set_option('display.max_columns', None, 'display.max_colwidth', None)

headers = {
    'content-type': 'application/json',
    'accept': 'application/json',
    'origin': 'https://www.tiffany.co.uk',
    'referer': 'https://www.tiffany.co.uk/jewelry/shop/necklaces-pendants/sort-relevance/',
    'x-ibm-client-id': 'b9a8bfef128b495f8f17fb3cdeba5555',
    'x-ibm-client-secret': '73805214423d4AaebC96aD5581dbcf0b',
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/109.0.0.0 Safari/537.36'
}

s = requests.Session()
s.headers.update(headers)

big_df = pd.DataFrame()
for x in tqdm(range(0, 600, 60)):
    payload = '{"assortmentID":201,"sortTypeID":5,"categoryid":287465,"navigationFilters":[201287465,201],"recordsOffsetNumber":' + str(x) +',"recordsCountPerPage":60,"priceMarketID":"2","searchModeID":2,"siteid":2}'
    r = s.post('https://www.tiffany.co.uk/ecomproductsearchprocessapi/api/process/v1/productsearch/ecomguidedsearch', data=payload)
    df = pd.json_normalize(r.json()['resultDto']['products'])
    big_df = pd.concat([big_df, df], axis=0, ignore_index=True)
reduced_info_df = big_df[['name', 'friendlyUrl', 'price', 'extendedDescription']]
display(reduced_info_df)
```

Result in terminal:

```
100%
10/10 [00:05<00:00, 3.48it/s]
name    friendlyUrl price   extendedDescription
0   Tiffany T Smile Pendant in Yellow Gold, Small   /jewelry/necklaces-pendants/tiffany-t-smile-pendant-35189459/   930.00  in Yellow Gold, Small
1   Tiffany T T1 Circle Pendant in Yellow Gold, Large   /jewelry/necklaces-pendants/tiffany-t-t1-circle-pendant-69901190/   6975.00 in Yellow Gold, Large
2   Tiffany T medium smile pendant in 18k rose gold with diamonds.  /jewelry/necklaces-pendants/tiffany-t-medium-smile-pendant-67513290/    5850.00 NaN
3   Tiffany T diamond and mother-of-pearl circle pendant in 18k rose gold.  /jewelry/necklaces-pendants/tiffany-t-diamond-and-mother-of-pearl-circle-pendant-64026828/  3175.00 in 18k Rose Gold, 16-18"
4   Return to Tiffany™ Lovestruck Heart Tag Necklace in Silver, Medium  /jewelry/necklaces-pendants/return-to-tiffany-lovestruck-heart-tag-necklace-online-exclusive-70878178/  720.00  in Silver, Medium
... ... ... ... ...
589 Return to Tiffany™ mini double heart tag pendant in silver with enamel finish.  /jewelry/necklaces-pendants/return-to-tiffany-mini-double-heart-tag-pendant-GRP06366/   240.00  NaN
590 Return to Tiffany™ Heart Tag Chain Link Choker in Silver    /jewelry/necklaces-pendants/return-to-tiffany-heart-tag-chain-link-choker-19936562/ 670.00  in Silver
591 Paloma Picasso® Olive Leaf vine pendant in 18k rose gold.   /jewelry/necklaces-pendants/paloma-picasso-olive-leaf-vine-pendant-32371183/    1075.00 NaN
592 Tiffany T diamond and turquoise circle pendant in 18k rose gold.    /jewelry/necklaces-pendants/tiffany-t-diamond-and-turquoise-circle-pendant-66885445/    3350.00 in 18k Rose Gold, 16-18"
593 Paloma's Graffiti X pendant in 18ct rose gold, small.   /jewelry/necklaces-pendants/palomas-graffiti-x-pendant-GRP11482/    650.00  NaN
594 rows × 4 columns
```

There is more data in big dataframe - just review it. Pandas documentation can be found [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/index.html).